# To find the min and max after addition and subtraction from a range of numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am having a Algorithm question, in which numbers are been given from 1 to N and a number of operations are to be performed and then min/max has to be found among them.

Two operations - Addition and subtraction

and operations are in the form a b c d , where a is the operation to be performed,b is the starting number and c is the ending number and d is the number to be added/subtracted

for example

> suppose numbers are 1 to N 
>   and 
>   N =5

1 2 3 4 5

We perform operations as

1 2 4 5

2 1 3 4

1 4 5 6

By these operations we will have numbers from 1 to N as

1 7 8 9 5

-3 3 4 9 5

-3 3 4 15 11

So the maximum is 15 and min is -3

My Approach:
I have taken the lower limit and upper limit of the numbers in this case it is 1 and 5 only stored in an array and applied the operations, and then had found the minimum and maximum.

Could there be any better approach?

Comment: What language are you writing in?

Comment: @DougRamsey: I think it is not important here. Probably language-agnostic tag should be used.

Comment: @Luv: Do you have any information about the range of input?

Comment: @nhahtdh Yes The range of values are from 1 to 1000000

Comment: @Luv: Is the max/min operation frequent? Or only at the end?

Comment: @nhahtdh Only at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that all update (addition/subtraction) operations happen before finding max/min. I don't have a good solution for update and min/max operations mixing together.

You can use a plain array, where the value at index i of the array is the difference between the index i and index (i - 1) of the original array. This makes the sum from index 0 to index i of our array to be the value at index i of the original array.

Subtraction is addition with the negated number, so they can be treated similarly. When we need to add k to the original array from index i to index j, we will add k to index i of our array, and subtract k to index (j + 1) of our array. This takes O(1) time per update.

You can find the min/max of the original array by accumulating summing the values and record the max/min values. This takes O(n) time per operation. I assume this is done once for the whole array.

Pseudocode:

```
a[N] // Original array
d[N] // Difference array

// Initialization
d[0] = a[0]
for (i = 1 to N-1)
    d[i] = a[i] - a[i - 1]

// Addition (subtraction is similar)
add(from_idx, to_idx, amount) {
    d[from_idx] += amount
    d[to_idx + 1] -= amount
}

// Find max/min for the WHOLE array after add/subtract
current = max = min = d[0];
for (i = 1 to N - 1) {
   current += d[i]; // Sum from d[0] to d[i] is a[i]
   max = MAX(max, current);
   min = MIN(min, current);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally there is no "best way" to find the min/max in the performance point of view because it depends on how this application will be used.

-Finding the max and min in a list needs O(n) Time, so if you want to run many (many in the context of the input) operations, your approach to find the min/max after all the operations took place is fine.

-But if the list will hold many elements and you don’t want to run that many operations, you better check each result of the op if its a new max/min and update if necessary.

Comment: If the list is static (which is **not** the case here), max/min can be found in O(log n) with the right data structure.

Comment: Your answer is missing here and there. O(log n) time for finding max/min is possible with segment tree, but update operation will take O(n) in worst case. I can think of another solution using plain array with O(1) update operation, but worst case O(n) time for finding max/min.

Comment: There are many ways of finding min/max in O(log n) Time (FastSearch, Bin.Search, Quadratic Bin. Search). But why would updating ever need O(n) time in worst case? For 1 Operation it would allways need _constant_ Time.

Comment: Bin Search needs the array to be sorted. After addition/subtraction, the array is no longer sorted.

Comment: Segment tree is _not_ an option for this use case, it is a static data structure and therefore not able to be mainpulated. Besides every data struc. that offers finding min/max in O(n) time is sorted in some way.

Comment: It is an option. Segment Tree allows mass update to a whole range, IIRC.

Comment: this is only possible in linear time, so there would not be any benefit of using it.

Comment: You are right about that. Not sure about the upper bound, but the lower bound of update operation should be omega(k).